# Symfony 4 : Doctrine2 LAZY Fetch Collection still empty after calling the getter

Tags: orm, doctrine, symfony4

I have an issue with some entities : according to [the doctrine documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html#association-proxies), lazy loading should allow me to load my collection only when I call the getters, but it doesn't.

**Here is the relation description :**

One Location has many Venues, mapped by the Location "externalId" field.

**Here is a simplified code sample of my entities and their relation :**

```
// Location.php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\LocationRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="Location")
 */
class Location extends Entity
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", unique=true, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $locationId;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $externalId;

    /**
     * @var Venue[]|Collection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Venue", mappedBy="locationExternalId", orphanRemoval=true, fetch="LAZY")
     */
    protected $venues;

    /**
     * Location constructor.
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        $this->venues = new ArrayCollection;
        $this->hydrate($data);
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getLocationId()
    {
        return $this->locationId;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $locationId
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setLocationId($locationId)
    {
        $this->locationId = $locationId;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Venue[]|Collection
     */
    public function getVenues()
    {
        return $this->venues;
    }

    /**
     * @param Venue[]|Collection $venues
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setVenues($venues)
    {
        $this->venues = $venues;
        return $this;
    }
}

// Venue.php
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\VenueRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="Venue", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_Venue", columns={"location_id"})})
 */
class Venue extends Entity
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", unique=true, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $venueId;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $externalId;

    /**
     * @var Location
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Location", inversedBy="venues")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="location_external_id", referencedColumnName="external_id", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $locationExternalId;

    /**
     * Venue constructor.
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        $this->hydrate($data);
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getVenueId()
    {
        return $this->venueId;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $venueId
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setVenueId($venueId)
    {
        $this->venueId = $venueId;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getExternalId()
    {
        return $this->externalId;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $externalId
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setExternalId($externalId)
    {
        $this->externalId = (int)$externalId;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Location
     */
    public function getLocationExternalId()
    {
        return $this->locationExternalId;
    }

    /**
     * @param Location $locationExternalId
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setLocationExternalId($locationExternalId)
    {
        $this->locationExternalId = $locationExternalId;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**If I load a Location, Venues is not initialized, that's what is expected :**

```
// Controller.php
use App\Entity\Basketball\Location;
use App\Entity\Basketball\Venue;

$location = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Location::class)->findOneBy(['externalId' => 1]);
dump($location);

// Dump results
App\Entity\Location {#1438 ▼   #locationId: 1644  
#externalId: 1
#venues: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#1450 ▼
    -snapshot: []
    -owner: App\Entity\Location {#1438}
    -association: array:15 [ …15]
    -em: Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager {#75 …11}
    -backRefFieldName: "locationExternalId"
    -typeClass: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata {#1441 …}
    -isDirty: false
    #collection: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#1700 ▶}
    #initialized: false
```

**But it should by calling the getter, and it's not working as expected**

```
// Controller.php
dump($location->getVenues());

// Dump results
Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#1450 ▼
  -snapshot: []
  -owner: App\Entity\Location {#1438 ▶}
  -association: array:15 [ …15]
  -em: Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager {#75 …11}
  -backRefFieldName: "locationExternalId"
  -typeClass: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata {#1441 …}
  -isDirty: false
  #collection: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#1700 ▼
    -elements: []
  }
  #initialized: false
}
```

**Environment**

- Symfony v4.4.7
- Doctrine v2.7 ("doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle":
  "^3.3")
- By specifying "fetch=EAGER", it works, but I don't want to...

**Any idea? What should I do to initialize my collection?**

**Edit**

Thanks to [this Github issue](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/6307) I found a workaround by initializing the collection inside the getter but still; there should be a way to do it automatically :

```
public function getVenues()
{
    $this->venues->initialize();
    return $this->venues;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it really need to you? For initializing collection you need to call some method of this collection. If you are using `JMSSerializer` or `Symfony Serializer` you can just return the serialized data, serializers do all job for you, because they call `toArray` method, that initialize your collection.

Comment: Well thank you very much, you are right. The documentation is unclear, but "on first access" means by calling a method of the collection. I don't use JMSSerializer nor Symfony Serializer but I can manually call the toArray method and it works fine :
`$location->getVenues()->toArray();`